# Starting tomcat with custom jvm without having to change JAVA_HOME and PATH on linux

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, jvm

I'm working with a server that needs to use several JVMs and the one I would like to use with my tomcat 7.0.28 is Oracle Server JRE 7. My Tomcat should not use the global JVM and I cannot change the environment variables either. I have checked what the internet has to say about this and tried to set JAVA_HOME in [tomcat-dir]/bin/catalina.sh but it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can set your JAVA_HOME  here

- for linux :  [tomcat-dir]/bin/setclasspath.sh
- for window : [tomcat-dir]/bin/setclasspath.bat

Comment: Can I just add `export JAVA_HOME="mypath"` anywhere in the file?